# Best file and dir permissions for zend?

Tags: zend-framework, permissions

What are the best permission settings to folders and files within a Zend application with  public pages and pages only accessible after login?

My guess is:

All folders including modules, controllers, models and views: 755 Everyone can read the directory, but its contents can only be changed by the user.

All files: 644 Only the owner has read and write permissions; the group and others can read only.

For a public folder that allows uploading and deleting users private files: 700, 
The private file itself 600.

Is this interpretation just? 
I am wondering if permissions for the backend of an application after a user is logged in should better be 750 or even 700 for folders and 640 (or 600?) for files, making them inaccessible for the rest of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *web server's* user is the one accessing the file system, not the end user. This is normally `www-data` for Linux systems running Apache. You should therefore base your permissions on that user/group.

The client however should only have read access to the root of the site, which is the `/public` folder. The public folder will contain the front-end images, js, css and `index.php` which is Zend's single point of entry.

Comment: Yes, so maybe that was a silly question. Now if the webserver is the user, who is group and where do the clients come in when setting permissions on folders/files? I am still trying to grasp this, could you maybe refer me to some good information where I can read up on this?